# Want to overwrite the text content of standard error message displayed on custom page

Tags: error-messages

I am using validation with help of standard error messages on a field. Is there a workaround to manipulate the standard text displayed on error message. ???

Comment: If you're using a validation rule, you can just change the error message configured. To contextualise it, you can catch the exception in your controller and add a custom Apex PageMessage

Comment: No, I am not using validation rule.I am doing this on  Standard field "Reply Body". This field is required by default. So without any validation rule sales force throws error when it is submitted as empty. And I want to manipulate text content of this error.

Comment: Check the field in your controller before your DML statement and add your own error message if blank.

Comment: Thanks, this was useful. On checking the field value in  controller and displaying it on page with <messages /> tag, I have end up with 2 error messages. One is from controller and other is the standard. How can we remove the standard one???

Comment: Some javascript (jquery perhaps) to hide the standard error message? Think standard error messages have a peculiar class (pbError or such?)

Comment: Since you're using a controller, and adding your own message, don't insert/update the record if the required field is missing. Something like `if (rec.replybody == null) { add error message to the page; return null; } else { insert rec;  }`

Answer (score 2):

Removing the duplicates - I built a bit of infrastructure to do this. There may be simpler solutions

In a class called Util, three methods:

```
  public static void addVFPageMessage(ApexPages.Severity sev, String msg, Exception e) {  
if (!Util.isExceptionAlreadyInVFMsgContext(e))
    ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(sev,msg, 
                            (e != null && 
                             (e.getTypeName() == 'System.DmlException' ||
                              e.getTypeName() == 'MyException'
                             )
                                 ? Util.friendlifyException(e.getMessage()) 
                                 : Util.showException(e)) 
                      ));
```

}

```
//  ---------------------------------------
//  friendlifyException
//  ---------------------------------------
public static String friendlifyException(String errMsg) {

  String     res         = errMsg;
  String     sysErrPrefix  = 'FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION,';
  Integer sysErrPrefixIndex  = errMsg.lastIndexOf(sysErrPrefix);
  if (sysErrPrefixIndex != -1)  // Strip out user unfriendly message prefix
      res = errMsg.subString(sysErrPrefixIndex + sysErrPrefix.length());
    String     myErrPrefix  = 'MyException';
  Integer myErrPrefixIndex  = errMsg.lastIndexOf(myErrPrefix);
  if (myErrPrefixIndex != -1)  // Strip out user unfriendly message prefix
      res = errMsg.subString(myErrPrefixIndex + myErrPrefix.length());  
  Integer stackTraceIndex    = res.indexOf('Class.');
  if (stackTraceIndex != -1)   // Strip out the stack trace at end of some messages
    res = res.subString(0,stackTraceIndex);
  return res;
}

  //  ------------------------------------------
  //  showException
  //  ------------------------------------------
public static String showException(Exception e) {
 return e != null ? e.getTypeName() + ' ' + e.getMessage() + ' line:' + e.getLineNumber() + '\n' + e.getStackTraceString() : '';
```

}

and in a controller, I do the following:

```
   // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// EXTENDED METHOD  - save          : Save as VF page 
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
public PageReference  save() {

 PageReference resPg;
 try{
    update this.oppo;        
}
    catch(DmlException e){
      Util.addVFPageMessage(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,'[OCE-03] Save failed, reason: ',e);
    }

 return resPg;
```

}